# What layer of abstraction should be tested

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, bdd

Let's say we have some functionality to write. It should validate csv file with some company data - one company per row. I'd like to write tests for this functionality. Today I had some conversation with my colleague and we can't decide which approach is better or maybe we are both wrong:

1. Writing tests at the level of some service which is entry point of validation. It has one method:

   ```
   ProcessingResult process(CsvFile csvFile)
   ```

   The test for IBAN number looks like this:

   ```
   // given
   valid csv row with invalid value in IBAN column
   // when
   service called
   // then
   result is validation failure with INVALID_IBAN error reason
   ```
2. Writing tests for specific validators. This approach assumes that there are few validators responsible for some groups of columns ex. `CompanyNameValidator`, `AccountNumberValidator` and so on.

First approach is good because it let us to refactor whole validation process without touching tests. I tried it and completely changed implementation running tests after every step and I was pretty confident I'm not breaking anything. This approach has cons as well. Let's say I have a test for company name and for IBAN. Consider implementation checking company name before IBAN. Let's say this name check is broken. Now test for IBAN is broken as well (the company name broke it). Is it ok or not?

Second approach won't have above problem as the company name is validated by different validator than IBAN. However it makes bigger refactoring impossible. If we wanted to change implementation and resign from multiple validators approach we would have to modify tests as well as we are testing them not the whole functionality.

Which approach is better or maybe there is another way to test this kind of code I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main subject I enjoy teaching my teams:

### Do your best to avoid coupling your tests with implementation details because unit test, especially in a TDD context, is about refactoring, not testing.

Testing specific validators will lead to brittle tests because the capacity of refactoring will be severely altered.

Indeed, what if tomorrow you or your teammate have a better way of designing code that involve a different nature of validation?

What if tomorrow you let a third party library do the validation work?
What if tomorrow you want to combine/merge some validators?

My point is: **Always unit test at the API level**, **like the first approach you mentioned**.
This way, you will be able to refactor your code without breaking any test.

Your test should not be aware of the strategy you use to make the work done.
It should only be focused with the entry point: the API (generally a `public` method in Java/C# etc).

People complain about unit testing wasting their time; and the symptom is unique:
In their way, tests are coupled to the implementation details; so break too easily during the refactoring step.

Don't write tests files for every validation separately, unless your listening of your tests when something breaks becomes too difficult to figure out.
Resist to do it as long as you can otherwise you'll fall into the trap where you won't want to refactor since you won't "allow" your existing tests break (a kind of sad human behaviour).

> Let's say I have a test for company name and for IBAN. Consider
>   implementation checking company name before IBAN. Let's say this name
>   check is broken. Now test for IBAN is broken as well (the company name
>   broke it).

**This point does clearly not depend upon a testing strategy.**
Your algorithm should be adapted according to the related user story:
**Are validation "fail-fast" ones (in that case, failure in checking company name interrupted the whole process) or not?**
Just write another test where the context is a successful company name checking and a failed IBAN validation; but keep targeting the API.

If you want some additional information, I suggest you to watch [that video](https://vimeo.com/68375232); the best I've ever watched on the subject.

Comment: _don't write tests for every validation separately_ - does your suggestion to write one test for all validation cases and assert them all at once?

Comment: No, one test should focus on a sole purpose.
So if you have 4 validation cases, you would have 4 tests. 
You don't test all your "branches" of validation in one step. 
Make as many tests targeting API as you need to test each branch.
If you practice TDD, it should be natural since you can't write production code unless a test expects it ;)
The only case where you may want to test ALSO separately (and may discard those low-level tests afterwards) is when dealing with combinatorial explosion: https://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2015/01/26/review-of-ian-cooper-tdd-where-did-it-all-go-wrong/

Comment: Sorry, than I didn't understand correctly what you mean by _In contradiction to @Fabio suggestion, don't write tests for every validation separately_

Comment: If you are testing separately each validation, you are coupling the implementation detail to the test.
The only case where it makes sense is when you are dealing with a combinatorial explosion (not often the case though), where it's not easy to test the combination through the API only, as it would lead to a huge amount of tests. For instance, you may want to test the first validation fails but the three nexts succeed; the second fails and three one does too etc.

Comment: By _ testing separately_ I meant to write separate test for every validation case. Sorry for being not so clear.

Comment: If that meant through the API, so yes it makes a huge sense ;) 
As long as you are not creating 4 unit tests FILES targeting each one those low-level validator classes.

Comment: I understood your initial sentence as advising to create unit test FILES instead of just separate unit tests in a same file ;)
Indeed, the OP evokes separate validators classes and asks about testing them separately through their eventual own unit test files.
The term **separate** for the OP means separate files, not just separate unit tests in a same file.
I've updated my answer so, removing your reference.

Comment: So in a nutshell, we're on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

First approach will bring more value, as you noticed, because you can freely play with implementation.

> Let's say I have a test for company name and for IBAN. Consider
>   implementation checking company name before IBAN. Let's say this name
>   check is broken. Now test for IBAN is broken as well (the company name
>   broke it). Is it ok or not?

Write tests for every validation test case separately. Then you will have clean "test report" where name of test will tell you exact problem you have without reading/opening failed test message.

However because you reading files, suggest to abstract file reading, then your tests become little bid more faster and do not affect on the maintaining of validation logic.

Comment: Hi Fabio. Thanks for answer. I do have separate tests for different validations. In the cited part ther test for company name and IBAN are two different tests. In first I break compoany name value and call validation and in second one I break IBAN and call validation. The point was: if implementation first tests company name and it's validator is broken both tests will go red. Test for IBAN will break even though IBAN validator is ok. It will break because valid company name will be improperly marked as invalid by coresponding broken validator.

Comment: @JulianRubin you should configure every test case so that it pass only when tested validation fail. So for company name you configure test where only company name validation is "broke" and for IBAN you configure test where only IBAN validation "broke"

Comment: I agree. Let's consider following situation though. I'm writing test for IBAN. I pass the valid csv row with broken IBAN only so company name is valid. I expect test to fail if underneath IBAN validation is broken. For some reason implementation of NAME validation is broken. The other test for name validation is now red. Test for IBAN is red as well because implementation says the valid company is invalid. What about this case?

Comment: @JulianRubin, In this case you see that tests complains about company name, even company name is valid. So you will investigate company validation logic. I think in your particular case it is ok to have such behaviour, because your test covering full implementation.

Comment: Fully agree with the last comment of @Fabio.
It's not an issue if both fail, even if the last one should have passed (company name checking and thus impacting IBAN one), as long as you are testing the full logic of your use case (good practice!), not a collaborator or a method (bad practice!).